# Using an LLC to buy property in Spain

Tags: united-states, real-estate, foreign-exchange, limited-liability-company

I am considering entering into an agreement with another couple (friends of mine) to purchase a piece of property in Spain.
The apartment would be primarily for our own use. However, we could both foresee renting the place periodically while we are both not there.  So potentially there would be some short-term rental income.

We would like to enter into the agreement spelling out the rules carefully so that we don't encounter problems down the line.  Specifically, we want to deal with issues such as if one party wants out; taking on other investors; inheritance; running costs (taxes, utilities); etc.

We would enter into this agreement able to fund the entire purchase in cash.  So I would foresee funding the LLC in cash to make the purchase on our behalf.

The other couple and I are all US citizens.  But in the future there could be a foreign investor / partial owner.

Is the best vehicle for this a US-based multi-member LLC?  Specifically I am asking from a legal, administrative, and tax point of view.  In my investigation, it seemed so.  I was wondering if others have an opinion about another legal structure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you need a legal consultation with regards to the partnership formation. From tax perspective, you'll need to check how the LLC would be treated by the Spanish law, and you would probably want to talk  to someone familiar with both the US and Spanish taxation, and the tax treaty between them. This is not a DIY situation.